# NonUniqueObjectException on saving joined tables

Tags: java, forms, orm

I have two related tables in a many to many relation: `Role` and `Permission`. The join table is `RolePermission`.

The `Role` object has a list of permission. it looks like this:

```
private Set<Permission> Permissions;    

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
@JoinTable(name = "permission_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"),
           inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "permission_id"))
public Set<ObjectPermission> getObjectPermissions() {
    return objectPermissions;
}
```

In a certain time I want to add permissions to a role:

```
role.getObjectPermissions().add(permission);
roleDAO.saveOrUpdate(role);
```

Both the role and the permission exist already in the db, each in its table. I want to add a record to the relation table, that will point both on the role and the permission:

```
role.addObjectEntryPermissionRole(permission);
roleDAO.saveOrUpdate(role);
```

The problem is that it looks like it's trying to save the permission itself! Then it throws this error:

```
org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session: [com.XXX.model.Permission#11]
```

Could somebody tell me what's the problen? what did I do wrong?

Comment: what addObjectEntryPermissionRole method looks like ? Are the Role or Permission objects detached (did you get them in another hibernate session ?) ?

Comment: I don't understand the two code snippets. Are you calling both of them? Also, what is the content of `addObjectEntryPermissionRole`?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Removing `cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }` resolved the issue.